# kartik gridview export bad request

Tags: yii2

Im using kartik\gridview, Previously my export was working perfectly, but now When i try to export data of any format (pdf, json, excel etc) in the gridview i get
for pdf i get a blank pdf
for json and excel the messege is the same, i get :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>408 Request Timeout</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Timeout</h1>
<p>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</p>
</body></html>
```

i run composer update a few times in the last few weeks so im not in aposition to 
know which update broke this.

I have tried also create a new yii2-basic project and tried this feature as well, its still doesn't work, 
so it not a problem with my project.

i have looked at your ExportController/actionDownload and the request is getting to it, 
with all the data. 
and still i have not been able to locate why this issue is arising.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by embedding the following code to your view layout files head section. The view layout file (e.g. main.php) is typically located in your application views/layouts directory.

```
// main.php
<head>
// other meta tags
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
</head>
```